# EditText android:textSelectHandle icon's onTouch listener

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to override **android:textSelectHandle icon's onTouch** listener

[image]

which method to override?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `android:textCursorDrawable`

In Layout

```
<EditText  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
    />
```

Than create drawalble xml: color_cursor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="3dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"  />
</shape>
```

Comment: thanks Palak but I'm looking for onTouch listener for that blue icon. EditText's onTouch listener isn't called once user drags that blue icon.